# Internet Explorer cannot display SVG from style class property

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, svg, icons

I probably hate IE as much as you all do but I'm doing some testing in IE and this doozy came up, I am stumped.

Only for IE, the SVG icons are not showing up, only the background color is. Not my work but someone before me used an "i" tag with a class (icon-outline-email) and pointed the class to two different mask properties and a background color property.

```
<i class="appkiticon icon-outline-email icon-size-16 email-icon">&nbsp;</i>
```

icon-outline-email is defined in the external stylesheet as:

```
    .icon-outline-email{background-color:#333;
     mask:url(./images/component/icons/outline/svg/Email.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-mask:url(./images/component/icons/outline/svg/Email.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%}
```

When viewed in Chrome/FF all is fine, but for IE 11, only the background-color comes through. I have had it working by adding in an additional background url with linear gradients property but then was told not to alter the appkit since it's used by other sites.

My question is this, is there a way to have IE show these icons in an Angular setting (via internal css stylesheet injection) or is there a npm out there (modernizr?) that could correct the issue sitewide?

Any help is appreciated, if you need more clarification... please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Does your code has this line in it? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> If not than try to add it and check the result.

Comment: I did run it through IE Developer Tools emulation to include Edge and it did not change anything.

Comment: You not need to run from developer tools. You just need to add that code in your HTML page in head section. Is that code available in your HTML file?

Comment: I've placed it in the head and it had no effect on the svg icons. They still cannot be viewed in IE 11.

Comment: I try to refer the documentation and find that IE does not supports CSS masks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask and https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

Comment: That part I understand regarding the masks, it does work when I use a separate external css file. I've had to use the "background:" property to make it appear in IE. However, this does not solve the issue of when I need to change the fills with a hover state.  P.S. Thank you very much for your assistance so far.

Comment: Can you try to provide any working example with IE? I will again try to make a test.